# Showing time problem xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Hai, I have create a iPhone project where I need to show the current  time of the day.In my application, one of the view has a textfield and when then view is appear the current time of that moment should be displayed.

I am a new iPhone developer and i have no idea about this. Please any one can help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What worked?  What didn't?  Please post some code and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this in your viewDidLoad method:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
textField.text = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
[formatter release];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

 [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

 NSString*tempooggi = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

 [tempo setText:(tempooggi)];
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation with your answer